# How can I SIMPLY Toggle/Hide a Menu from sub-menu in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, hamburger-menu

So I've read through a few Stacks and am finding that I must create separate directives to hide/toggle a menu from it's sub-menu items.

I want the menu to HIDE when ANY of the sub-menu items are clicked.

But I feel like there has to be an easier way and am wondering if anyone knows if there is or not?

As of right now, I have my code set to list items that create tabs with values assigned to them. When a sub-menu item is selected, it hides all the tabs EXCEPT for the selected tab value.  This way there is no page reload and no parameters being passed.

```
<a href ng-click="toggle = !toggle">=</a>
<ul ng-show="toggle">
  <li><a id="Home" ng-click="navi.selectTab(1)">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="About" ng-click="navi.selectTab(2)">About</a></li>
  <li><a id="Contact" ng-click="navi.selectTab(3)">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

...<div ng-show="navi.isSelected(1)">...
...<div ng-show="navi.isSelected(2)">...
...<div ng-show="navi.isSelected(3)">...
```

I'm hoping for a quick fix.  I've attached a function prototype with plunkr:
    [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/k9dXfU6sA1YZbQV9JsBI)

Again, this is just a prototype. The final version will be fancied up. I'm just looking for functionality advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you can do like:

```
<a href ng-click="toggle = !toggle">=</a>
<ul ng-show="toggle">
  <li><a id="Home" ng-click="navi.selectTab(1); toggle = false">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="About" ng-click="navi.selectTab(2); toggle = false">About</a></li>
  <li><a id="Contact" ng-click="navi.selectTab(3); toggle = false">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or create a function that will do both - `selectTab(index)` and `toggle = false` . And call it in `ng-click`

Comment: I had thought about creating the function with 2 params. Maybe I'll keep looking into that.  The toggle = false doesn't seem to work. In fact it disables my <a> tags all together.

Comment: Hm, please look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PEKf6o11wL42qam3fHwn?p=preview. Isn't it the behaviour you asked for?

Comment: Holy crap yes... You semicolon separated it. I was using commas.  You rock Serhiy Chupryk